# get instagram saved posts

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram has a newish feature in their app (not on web) that let you save posts.
This is a good feature because, unlike liking a photo, no one else will know you saved the photo.

The question is: are these posts saved locally on your machine (or at least a reference to these posts is saved locally on your phone)? and if they are, is there a way to access this data?

In case your saved posts are not saved locally, but on the cloud, is there an api command to retrieve info about these posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These "bookmarked" posts are saved to your account (in the cloud), and not on your local device.

Unfortunately it doesn't seems like they have an endpoint for that..yet
See [Instagram API Changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)

Comment: Thanks! do you know where I can contact instagram about this issue and ask them when and are they going to add this to their API?

Comment: @DannySivan They have a Google group (which is due to be closed "soon"), they refer visitors to this URL https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/ . Hope this helps!